org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3Config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
I was working on the AWS SDK v2 spring boot project on Java 17 using Maven which I tried to run the file but I got an error saying "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3Config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed". I tried everything as I could but so far have not been able to solve the problem. Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

DemoApplication

package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;

@Configuration
public class S3Config {
    @Value("${region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Bean
    S3Client s3Client() {
        AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);
        return S3Client.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .build();
    }
}


S3Config
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import com.example.demo.services.S3Service;

public class S3Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private S3Service s3Service;
    @GetMapping("/listAllObjects")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> viewObjects() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(s3Service.listObjects(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


S3Controller
package com.example.demo.services;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class S3Service {
    @Value("${bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    private final S3Client s3Client;

    public S3Service(S3Client s3Client) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }

    public List<String> listObjects() {
        ListObjectsResponse listObjectsResponse = s3Client.listObjects(b -> b.bucket(bucketName));
        return listObjectsResponse.contents().stream()
                .map(S3Object::key)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

S3Service
spring.application.name=demo
aws.region=`${region}`
aws.accessKey=`${accessKey}`
aws.secretKey=`${secretKey}`
aws.bucketName=`${bucketName}`
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

application.properties

AWS SDK for Java V2 Service clients work fine in a Spring Boot app. However, I am not a fan of trying to autowire an AWS Service class.
Try to take a different approach. Try using constructor-based autowiring.
The Controller...
 public class S3Controller {

      private final Foo foo;

        @Autowired
      S3Controller (
        Foo foo
    ) {
        this.foo= foo;
    }
    
        public void someMethod() {
            // Use the S3Service through the Foo class
            foo.getS3Service().someOperation();
    }

The @Component Class that uses the S3Service client.
@Component
public class Foo {
    @Singleton
    @Bean
    public S3Service getS3Service() {
    return S3Client.builder()
         .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
         .build();
    }

    // Get the byte[] from this Amazon S3 object.
    public byte[] getObjectBytes (String bucketName, String keyName) {
        s3 = getClient();
        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key(keyName)
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            return objectBytes.asByteArray();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

 }
    

By autowiring the Foo class (that class in which the AWS Service CLient is used) in the S3Controller, you are maintaining a clear separation of concerns. The S3Controller is responsible for handling the controller-level logic, while the Foo class encapsulates the service-level logic, including the management of the S3Service.
Declaring the S3Service as a singleton within the Foo class allows you to easily manage the lifecycle and sharing of the S3Service instance across your application.
You can find an example of a Spring BOOT app using Amazon S3 in the AWS COde Lib here:
Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java

What is keyName? Is it accessKey or secretKey?

You are referring to the  GetObjectRequest. Here key is the name of the object in the S3 bucket. ie -- lake.png as shown in the article/example I linked you to.  As far as Creds. I use the Default credentials provider chain as explained in the Java V2 Dev Guide here --  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html
